# Slack API not returning private channels

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to obtain a list of private channels in Slack (on a per-user basis is fine), but I'm having trouble seeing this information. I installed my application into the workspace in Slack originally and got an OAuth token in the form `xoxp-4...........`.

**App OAuth token**

When I try to use the slack API (node SDK) then I only get the publicly listed channels.

```
await new WebClient(`xoxp-4.....`)
    .conversations       
    .list({ exclude_archived: true })
).channels
```

I get the same if I try using the Slack API tester to grab a [channel list](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list/test).

**User OAuth token**
I've followed the [OAuth 2.0](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) process to obtain a token for a given user (myself). I think I've done all this correctly (here's a response):

```
{
        ok: true,
        access_token: 'xoxp-4.........',
        scope: 'identify,bot,commands,channels:history,groups:history,im:history,mpim:history,channels:read,emoji:read,groups:read,im:read,search:read,team:read,users:read,users:read.email,usergroups:read,users.profile:read,chat:write:user,chat:write:bot,links:read',
        user_id: 'UD......',
        team_name: '............',
        team_id: '.......',
        scopes: ['identify',
            'bot',
            'commands',
            'channels:history',
            'groups:history',
            'im:history',
            'mpim:history',
            'channels:read',
            'emoji:read',
            'groups:read',
            'im:read',
            'search:read',
            'team:read',
            'users:read',
            'users:read.email',
            'usergroups:read',
            'users.profile:read',
            'chat:write:user',
            'chat:write:bot',
            'links:read'
        ]
    }
```

Interestingly I discovered this provides me with exactly the same OAuth token if I goto the application management (I assume because it was me who installed the app to the workspace).

Obviously, because it's the same token, I don't get permissions to see the private channels still, even though as far as I'm aware I should be able to do everything I can do as a user?

Can anyone point me to what I might be missing?

Comment: I had a similar issue, afarid i can't find the link for the exact solution. I think it was something to do with having to use legacy tokens to get access. https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens

I was using python not node though, and this was last year so things may have changed.

Comment: @Emile I just tried a token from the legacy-tokens page and with the `channels.list` api function it didn't seem to make any different unfortunately.

Comment: I realised just now as well that i was downloading from desktop so not quite the same scenario as you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why you do not get the private channels is that you are not requesting them.

The [`conversations.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list) method will return public channels by default only. To also get private channels you need set the parameter `types` accordingly. e.g. `types = public_channel,private_channel`.

Similar with calling [`channels.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list). `Channels.list` will only return public channels. If you want to get the private channels you need to call [`groups.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/groups.list). (note that private channels are called groups in the API for historical reasons).

In general I would recommend using `conversations.list`, which is more powerful and the recommended approach to get all types of conversations.

Comment: Thanks again Eric - `conversations.list` is actually what I'm using for history (but not for the channel list for some reason). I'll switch it over and accept once I confirm it works.

Comment: Happy to help. I guess you might also be interested in getting all private channels of a workspace. If so check out this link for an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690761/get-a-list-of-all-private-channels-with-slack-api

Comment: Yeah, I've already seen your answer there actually since posting this. It's the approach I'm using actually :)

Comment: Actually types=private_channel doesn't return the list of private channels.

Comment: @TaronMehrabyan it sure does

Comment: It used to return all of them but now it only returns some of the private channels, even though channel name and users hasn't changed

Comment: similar issue: "public_channel,private_channel" returns less items than "public_channel" only

Comment: @ErikKalkoken, can I fetch private channels using xoxb token?